# Serial ports registered but /dev/ttyS4 and ttyS5 files missing (Ubuntu 18.04, Intel Apollo Lake SoC)

Tags: drivers, kernel, intel, serial-port

I can't find a way to make the serial ports work on my computer.

If I run dmesg I see that they get recognized and registered

```
dw-apb-uart.0: ttyS4 at MMIO 0x9131e000 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
serial serial0: tty port ttyS4 registered
dw-apb-uart.1: ttyS5 at MMIO 0x9131c000 (irq = 6, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
serial serial1: tty port ttyS5 registered
```

But then ls /dev/ttyS* shows that the S4 and S5 files are missing - it goes from ttyS3 to ttyS6.

I found different forums describing similar errors, but none of the solutions helped. I tried loading the intel-lpssi-pci module, 8250_lpss module, recompiled the kernel to have them built-in, changed BIOS settings so that the HSUART would work on PCI mode instead of ACPI, I also tried creating the files with mknod and using setserial, but I get "no such device or address" on the newly created files.

What can I do?

Comment: I tried with Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.4.0-176-generic) and the serial port /dev nodes are there, but dmesg shows no "tty port ttyS4 registered". I'll be trying with kernel 5.14 now to see if the problem is solved, otherwise I'll just downgrade

Comment: Have you tried `cd /dev; MAKEDEV ttyS4` ?

Answer (score 0):

After speaking with the device vendor, it turned out it was a wrong BIOS setting.